# Completeness theorem in propositional logic implies the compactness theorem

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I would like some help with proving the compactness theorem in propositional logic using the completeness theorem, that is:
Given that every wff is a tautology iff it is a theorem, prove that a set $\Sigma$ of wff is satisfiable iff it is finitely satisfiable.

Comment: Suppose that $\Sigma$ is not satisfiable, so you can prove a contradiction from it. But a proof has finitely many hypothesis. Now use completeness

Comment: Ok so if $\Sigma$ is not satisfiable then $\Sigma \models \phi \land \lnot \phi $. Then by completeness we have $\Sigma \vdash \phi \land \lnot \phi $. Therefore there is a finite subset $\Sigma_0$ of $\Sigma$ s.t. $\Sigma_0  \vdash \phi \land \lnot \phi $. But then I would have $\Sigma_0 \models \phi \land \lnot \phi$ which cannot be true due to $\Sigma_0$ being satisfiable. Is this correct?

Comment: @Matheo yes, that is correct